# Как анимировать стрелочки на картинке?

Tags: html, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, gif

Появилась идея сделать анимированные потоки воздуха(стрелки) на сайте с исчезновением в конце. Только не знаю как лучше реализовать.

[image: Воздушные потоки]

Как вариант думаю нарисовать в Figma стрелку и искажая её сделать несколько кадров анимации с несколькими стрелками так, чтобы получилось будто они двигаются в лево и склеить в гифку, потом вставить на сайт, а слева от этой гифки добавить блок с белой тенью чтобы получился эффект рассеивания.

Подскажите, правильно ли я придумал и как вообще такое делается?

Comment: Если вам не жалко пользователей - идеально, можно вместо гифки видео запилить в 1080(или 4к чего мелочится?) А иначе - svg

Comment: рисовать path можно в обычном inkscape, анимировать можно на обычном css3 изменяя stroke-dasharray + stroke-dashoffset вот таким образом: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKaVxxw но пристыковать треугольники при таком подходе будет проблематично

Answer (score 4):

> Подскажите, правильно ли я придумал и как вообще такое делается?

Можно сделать по разному:

1. Каждой стрелке будет соответствовать своя растровая отдельная картинка и её можно перемещать командами трансформации
2. Использовать анимацию трансформации контуров стрелки, используя атрибут `d` `path` и одновременно перемещать стрелку, как в способе 1. Но это очень трудоемкий процесс при подготовки path для морфинга стрелки.
3. Использовать [**textPath**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) для перемещения стрелки-символа юникода. Например такого  `&#129192;`

Этот способ интересен тем, что на одну траекторию для `textPath` можно повесить сколько угодно символов стрелки

```
<textPath  xlink:href="#red" letter-spacing="40"  startOffset="0%"> 
&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129
185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;
</textPath>
```

В векторном редакторе рисуем трассы для движения стрелок. Их будет 4 для 4-х групп стрелок  На рисунке они разного цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже пример одной группы стрелок, которая будет перемещаться по одному пути (на рисунке это красная линия)

*Анимация начнется после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="877" height="347" viewBox="0 0 877 347" >  
  <defs>
    <path id="red" d="m840.5 188.3c0 0-32 38.4-54.7 41.8-43.3 6.6-80.6-35.3-123.3-45C610.1 173.1 550.2 192.7 501.8 169 461.8 149.5 452.6 84.4 409.7 72.6 341.4 53.7 273.5 146.7 204.8 129.4 168.8 120.3 163.9 43.3 124.4 52.2 76.4 62.9 27.9 136.9 27.9 136.9" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#eb2323"/>
  </defs>   

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sghlt.png" width="100%" height="100%" />  

        <!-- Одиночная стрелка на верху кондиционера (просто для примера) -->
    <text id="arrow1" x="800" y="50" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue"><tspan> 
         &#129192;</tspan></text>   
         
      <text   dy="0px" dx="0" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue" letter-spacing="32"  >
        <textPath  xlink:href="#red" letter-spacing="40"  startOffset="0%"> &#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;
        <!-- Анимация стрелок по одному пути xlink:href="#red" -->
        <animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s" values="0%;100%"
         repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"   /> 
        </textPath>  
   </text>     
</svg>
```

*Добавляем другие группы стрелок*

Добавляются в секцию `<defs>` `path`- траектории движения стрелок и команды `textPath` для каждой группы стрелок с соответствующими `ID` path трассы

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="877" height="347" viewBox="0 0 877 347" >  
  <defs>
    <path id="red" d="m840.5 188.3c0 0-32 38.4-54.7 41.8-43.3 6.6-80.6-35.3-123.3-45C610.1 173.1 550.2 192.7 501.8 169 461.8 149.5 452.6 84.4 409.7 72.6 341.4 53.7 273.5 146.7 204.8 129.4 168.8 120.3 163.9 43.3 124.4 52.2 76.4 62.9 27.9 136.9 27.9 136.9" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#eb2323"/>
    <path id="purple" d="m865.2 246.2c0 0-71 15.2-101.9 1.1-32.3-14.8-37.2-64.9-68.6-81.5-30.8-16.3-73.2 5.6-104-10.7-26.8-14.2-29.9-59.9-58.6-69.8-32.6-11.2-71.4 4.1-101.1 21.6-27 15.9-33.9 56.6-61.8 70.9-26.7 13.7-59.7 10.5-89.7 8.5-39.8-2.6-53.7-21-116.6-26.9-98.3-4.3-17.4 110.6-142.6 97.6" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#d81b94"/>
  <path id="blue" d="m802 184c0 0-57.3 42.5-91.1 46.1-33.8 3.6-64.8-23.1-98.6-25.7-51-4-101.7 19.8-152.7 15.2C410 215.2 355.7 208.8 316.3 178.7 285.6 155.2 293.5 89.6 256.2 79.6c-34.7-9.3-59.2 44.3-94.3 51.9-14 3-29.1-7.5-42.8-3.3-28.8 8.8-42.4 46-70.8 55.8-0.3 0.1-1.1 0-1.1 0" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#325ada"/>
  <path id="black" d="m856.6 229.1c0 0-46.9 44.5-175.8-93.3-47-50.2-94.8 78.1-151.3 76.6-57.2-1.5-91.7-85.6-148.9-85.2-55.1 0.3-87.5 86.9-142.5 83.8C156 206.4 40.7 62.9 40.7 62.9v0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>  
  </defs>   

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sghlt.png" width="100%" height="100%" />  

 
  
        <!-- Одиночная стрелка -->
    <text id="arrow1" x="800" y="50" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue"><tspan> 
         &#129192;</tspan></text>   
         
      <text   dy="0px" dx="0" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue" letter-spacing="32"  >
        <textPath  xlink:href="#red" letter-spacing="40"  startOffset="0%"> &#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;
        <!-- Анимация стрелок по одному пути xlink:href="#red" -->
        <animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s" values="0%;100%"
         repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"  /> 
        </textPath>  
   </text>     
   
 <text   dy="0px" dx="0" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue" letter-spacing="32"   >
        <textPath  xlink:href="#purple"  startOffset="100%" > &#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185; 
        <!-- Анимация стрелок по одному пути xlink:href="#purple" -->
        <animate id="an2" attributeName="startOffset" begin="an1.begin+2s" dur="6s" values="0%;100%"
         repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"  /> 
        </textPath>  
   </text>    

<text   dy="0px" dx="0" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue" letter-spacing="32"  >
        <textPath  xlink:href="#blue"   startOffset="100%"> &#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;
        <!-- Анимация стрелок по одному пути xlink:href="#blue" -->
        <animate id="an3" attributeName="startOffset" begin="an1.begin+4s" dur="6s" values="0%;100%"
         repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"  /> 
        </textPath>  
   </text>    

<text   dy="0px" dx="0" font-size="42px" fill="dodgerblue" letter-spacing="32"  >
        <textPath  xlink:href="#black"   startOffset="100%"> &#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;&#129193;&#129185;
        <!-- Анимация стрелок по одному пути xlink:href="#black" -->
        <animate id="an4" attributeName="startOffset" begin="an1.begin+6s" dur="6s" values="0%;100%"
         repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive"  /> 
        </textPath>  
   </text>    
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне было бы ооочень интересна реализация изменения формы стрелки вдоль пути, а не только следование и поворот вдоль него. Возможно такое? Хотя, что возможно - это точно. Но, насколько сложно в реализации?

Comment: @UModeL это как раз способ 2 в начале ответа. Я делал такое не раз, но это очень муторно в векторном редакторе рисовать патчи морфинга стрелок.  Ошибка даже не с количеством узловых точек, а со сменой их типа ведет к дискретной анимации. Самое неприятное, что при перетаскивании узловыз точек векторный редактор может автоматически поменять тип узла. Поискать топики, где рассказано, как это делается?

Comment: нет, Саш, не надо. Раз настолько сложно, то подумаю пока сам.

Comment: @UModeL не сложно, просто очень трудоемко и времязатратно. Выглядит конечно такой морфинг очень выигрышно

Answer (score 2):

Мощные анимированные потоки воздуха:

```css
div {
  width: 100%; font-size: 50px; line-height: 28px; color: dodgerblue;
  transform: scale(-1, 1); animation: arrow 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0% {transform: scale(-1, 1) translateX(0);}
  100% {transform: scale(-1, 1) translateX(100%);}
}
```

```html
<div>&#10144;</div><div>&#10144;</div><div>&#10144;</div><div>&#10144;</div><div>&#10144;</div><div>&#10144;</div>
```